# How do you perform an animated rotate of an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rotation

I am just starting out using WPF. I want to rotate an image when i click a button but I don't want the image to rotate in one instant rotation. I want the use to see the image rotate one degree at a time. What is the easiest way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply a [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) to the Image, with its initial [Angle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.angle.aspx) set to 0.  Then animate the transform's Angle property in the normal way.

If you specifically want a discrete rotation, where the rotation visibly clicks over in one-degree jumps, use a DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames instead of a normal DoubleAnimation, and make each key frame a DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame.  (You'll probably want to generate the storyboard programmatically in this case because you'll have a lot of key frames.)

Comment: Can you point me to a place where there is a code demonstration of the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames?